# Compare adjacent cell in excel file if matching highlight: green if not then red and if they are not comparable then yellow based on unique key

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-formatting

I want to compare adjacent cell in this excel using unique key(here:'ID') and display the differences between them by highlighting them, and final result will be

[image: Excel File]

1. Matching - If all are green highlighted
2. Not comparable - If atleast one is yellow highlighted
3. Not Matching - If atleast one is Red highlighted

But I am not sure how I can achieve this using python. Any suggestions?

Ex: I Want to compare (C with D), (E with F) and (G with H)
Let's take C vs D
Ex: IF C2 = D2 then green highlighted if C2!= D2 then red and if any cell is blank(either C2 or D2) then yellow.

After that in Result column

1. If atleast one red cell then Result will be Not Matching.
2. If all are green then Result will be Match
3. If atleast one yellow cell then Result will be Not Comparable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi updated my post can you please help me.

Comment: Use text instead of images in question so, reproducing examples is easy. Do you want to do it from colors or logical operations? Why don't you do it in Excel Sheet itself?

Comment: Hi Bibhav, I want to automate actually and I want to use color.